# R for loop gives: Error in if (is.na(x)) return(0) else return(sign(x)) : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, for-loop, null, na

I am looping through a large data set and have isolated some groups that return the error:

Error in if (is.na(x)) return(0) else return(sign(x)) : 
  argument is of length zero

Other posts have suggested that this indicates the existence of NULLs. However,

> is.null(block_of_troublesome_data) 
>   [1] FALSE

manually inspecting the df does not show any na values either (which makes sense because I previously ran an na.omit() on the whole block.

What am I missing?

additional info: Here is the df that the loop is working on:

> data
>
> ## A tibble: 120 x 11

## Groups:   ecoregion_code [1]

ecoregion_code loc_major_basin    lake_id lake_name sample_date     y     m   doy value_ft season_code season
                                                     
 1             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  1999-07-29  1999     7   210 5.610236           2 Summer
 2             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2000-06-18  2000     6   170 6.496063           1 Spring
 3             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2000-07-04  2000     7   186 6.496063           2 Summer
 4             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2000-08-12  2000     8   225 6.496063           2 Summer
 5             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2000-08-26  2000     8   239 6.496063           2 Summer
 6             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2000-09-16  2000     9   260 6.496063           3   Fall
 7             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2001-06-03  2001     6   154 5.511811           1 Spring
 8             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2001-06-10  2001     6   161 5.511811           1 Spring
 9             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2001-06-17  2001     6   168 4.986877           1 Spring
10             40         7010103 01-0022-00    ISLAND  2001-10-18  2001    10   291 6.496063           3   Fall

## ... with 110 more rows

and the output of 'if (is.na(x)) return(0) else return(sign(x))'

> if (is.na(data)) return(0) else return(sign(data))
>   Error in Math.data.frame(data) : 
>     non-numeric variable in data frame: lake_idlake_namesample_dateseason
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (is.na(data)) return(0) else return(sign(data)) :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

and

> if (length(data)==0) 0 else if is.na(x) 0 else sign(data)
>   Error: unexpected symbol in "if (length(data)==0) 0 else if is.na"

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(x)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(x, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

All zero-length vectors are not `NULL` so you might want to test for `length(x)`:

```
# instead of ...
if (is.na(x)) return(0) else return(sign(x))
# try ...
if (length(x)==0) 0 else if is.na(x) 0 else sign(x)
# or equivalently ...
if(length(foo)==0 || is.na(foo)) 0 else sign(foo)
```

(You may or may not need `return(...)` here, that's another issue.)

A test case:

```
foo <- numeric(0)
is.null(foo) # FALSE
if(length(foo)==0) 0 else if(is.na(foo)) 0 else sign(foo)  # 0
if(length(foo)==0 || is.na(foo)) 0 else sign(foo)  # 0
```